# infimum of the function using derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How to calculate $ \inf (|\log x|-1)x^{\frac12} $
using derivatives $x\in (0,\infty) $

For $ x>1 $ $$ \frac{d}{dx}=\frac{\log x+1}{2x^{\frac12}}$$
And for $ x<1 $ $$ \frac{d}{dx}=\frac{-\log x-3}{2x^{\frac12}}$$

Comment: The infimum has to "occur" where the derivative is zero, or isn't defined, or at an "endpoint", right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should think on whether the infimum is aswell a minimum. If this is the case you can actually find the minimum by using the derivative. So the first problem is whether the inf is on the borders of you interval: but you can check that for $(x \rightarrow 0), f(x) \rightarrow 0$ and for $(x \rightarrow +\infty), f(x) \rightarrow +\infty$. Now you can study the derivative. Fisrt of all you can note that for $x \geq 1$ the derivative is always positive ( so $f(x) $ is increasing). In second place in $(0,1)$ the derivative $f'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x= \frac{1}{e^3}.$ But this is a maximum as you might see. Now if you consider $f(1)=-1$ you can say that this is the infimum of the function (it all comes form the signs of the derivative).